# net5.0 - Error receiving diferent size of byte array between Microservices

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-5

I have 2 Microservices (In a simple way to share it), here's the code from the "source" Microservice

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("resource")]
    public async Task<byte[]> LocateResource(Guid Id)
    {
        if (Id== Guid.Empty)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Id");
        }

        var (content, message) = await _repo.LocateResource(Id);
        if (!message.Equals("Success"))
        {
            throw new Exception(message);
        }
        // content.lenght equivalent to 56129
        return content;
    }
```

and then Here is the code for the "Client"

```
    public async Task<byte[]> ReadFile(Guid Id)
    {

        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{_urlOptions.Value.ReadFileEndpoint}?Id={Id}");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var file = await response.Content.ReadAsByteAsync();

        // file.lenght equivalent to 74000
        return file;
```

}

The problem is that I'm sending 56129 bytes and I'm receiving 74000 bytes in the "Client", and it looks like there is no explanation for this behavior. Can someone give me further details, please?

Comment: I assume `content` in the server code is actually `byte[]` and not some custom class that has a conversion operator to `byte[]` that might be the culprit?

Comment: Whan is `ReadAsByteAsync`? I do not see such a method for `HttpContent` class. Is it some kind of extension method?

Comment: In your ReadFile2 the Id in $"{_urlOptions.Value.ReadFileEndpoint}?Id={Id}" is a typo, as it it not passed into the function?

Answer (score 2):

You should return response of type `FileContentResult`. For example:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("file")]
        public IActionResult GetFile()
        {
            var result = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
            return this.File(result, "application/octet-stream");
        }
    }
}
```

`File` is a helper method defined in `ControllerBase` class.

By default ASP.NET serializes content to JSON and binary data is encoded using base64. That's why you get bigger response then you expect. The result from my example looks like this when encoded and serialized: `"AQIDBAUGBw=="`.

Answer (score 0):

ReadAsByteAsync actually exist in HttpContent.
I suggest you have a custom response class that handles conversion